# Singularities of a complex function

Tags: complex-analysis

I have a function of the form 
$$
\frac{\sqrt{z}}{\sqrt{1+z^2}}
$$
I want to find the singularities of it. Obviously there is a branch point at $z=0$ and $z=\infty$ because of $\sqrt{z}$, I'm all OK with that.

But regarding the lower term $\sqrt{1+z^2}$ -- what are $z=\pm i$, are they also branch points or essential singularities?

Comment: $z$=$\pm i$ are poles. This is so as the denominator vanishes but not the numerator.

Comment: @SwapnilTri No. They are **not** poles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are branch points. There is no way to define your function to be holomorphic on punctured neighbourhoods of $z = \pm i$.

Comment: Thanks, I also convinced myself of that. But I believe they are also essential singularities?

Comment: @BillyJean That depends on the definition of essential singularities you use. If your definition requires essential singularities to be isolated singularities, then no. If your definition of an essential singularity is "everything that is neither removable nor pole", then they are essential.